# JsonResult is sorted in opposite directions on client and server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I query my database and return data to the client. When I console.log the data on the client it is in alphabetical order:

```
[
   [{key='a',val=123},{key='a',val=666},{key='a',val=420}],
   [{key='b',val=999},{key='b',val=822},{key='b',val=314}],
   [{key='c',val=732},{key='c',val=444},{key='c',val=987}],
]
```

But when I run my unit tests the data is backwards!

```
[
   [{key='c',val=732},{key='c',val=444},{key='c',val=987}],
   [{key='b',val=999},{key='b',val=822},{key='b',val=314}],
   [{key='a',val=123},{key='a',val=666},{key='a',val=420}],
]
```

Maybe I am casting the object wrong?

```
JsonResult result = (JsonResult)target.GetStockHistory(new string[]{"ABCDEFG", "ZYXWVUT"});
IGrouping<string, StockRecord>[] allStocks = (IGrouping<string, StockRecord>[])result.Data;
```

I am positive that it being sorted in the console is not a result of the browser formatting it for me because the browser has no way of knowing what value to sort by. It's just parsing the JSON.

Here is my action method (not sure if sorting or subqueries is contributing to the problem)

```
    public ActionResult GetStockHistory(string[] symbols)
    {
        StockHistory stocks = new StockHistory();
        IEnumerable<StockRecord>[] records = repository.StockRecords
            .Where(r => symbols.Contains(r.Symbol))
            .GroupBy(r => r.Symbol)
            .Select(g =>
                g.OrderByDescending(g2 => g2.RecordDate)
                .Take(30)
                .OrderBy(g3 => g3.RecordDate))
            .ToArray();
        return Json(records, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Here is the test method

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Can_Get_Stocks() 
    {
        // arrange
        Mock<IStockHistory> mock = new Mock<IStockHistory>();
        mock.Setup(m => m.StockRecords).Returns(new StockRecord[] {
            new StockRecord { 
                Symbol = "ABCDEFG", 
                RecordDate = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1),
                 LowValue = 1,
                 HighValue = 10,
                AdjustedCloseValue = 8,
                CloseValue = 9,
                OpenValue = 7, 
                Volume = 13245
            },
            new StockRecord { 
                Symbol = "LMNOP", 
                RecordDate = new DateTime(2005, 1, 1),
                LowValue = 1,
                HighValue = 5,
                AdjustedCloseValue = 6,
                CloseValue = 5,
                OpenValue = 4, 
                Volume = 23456
            },
            new StockRecord { 
                Symbol = "ZYXWVUT", 
                RecordDate = new DateTime(2010, 1, 1),
                LowValue = 6,
                HighValue = 60,
                AdjustedCloseValue = 10,
                CloseValue = 10,
                OpenValue = 7, 
                Volume = 67891
            }
        }.AsQueryable());
        CommonController target = new CommonController(mock.Object);

        // act
        JsonResult result = (JsonResult)target.GetStockHistory(new string[]{"ABCDEFG", "ZYXWVUT"});
        IGrouping<string, StockRecord>[] allStocks = (IGrouping<string, StockRecord>[])result.Data;
        // allStocks is backwards!?!?! cats and dogs are getting along! 

        // assert
        Assert.AreEqual(2, allStocks.Length);
        Assert.AreEqual("ZYXWVUT", allStocks[0].ToArray()[0].Symbol);
        Assert.AreEqual("ABCDEFG", allStocks[1].ToArray()[0].Symbol);
        Assert.AreEqual(10, allStocks[0].ToArray()[0].CloseValue);
        Assert.AreEqual(9, allStocks[1].ToArray()[0].CloseValue);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that casting from  IEnumerable<StockRecord>[] to  IGrouping<string, StockRecord>[] in IGrouping<string, StockRecord>[] allStocks = (IGrouping<string, StockRecord>[])result.Data; comiling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collections, like SQL SELECT queries, are not guaranteed to be in any particular order - which means the results *may* be sorted.

In my experience, any of the `.To___()` calls undo any previously-specified `.OrderBy()` methods. So, when your code calls `.ToArray()` ***after*** `.OrderBy(g3 => g3.RecordDate)` it resets any sorting. The fact that the results are sorted on the client is likely just a fluke.

The solution would be to call `.ToArray()` earlier in the chain, `.OrderBy()` later, or make another call to `.OrderBy()` after the conversion to an array.

Comment: It was a combination of this and my answer below. Still a little confused about the fluke thing. I mean it's sorted right on the client now (after I got it sorted on the server) but maybe that's a fluke too.

Comment: _any of the .To___() calls undo any previously-specified .OrderBy() methods_ ==> no, that is no true.

Comment: @ken2k I probably should have phrased it, "are not guaranteed to maintain the sorting imposed by previous .OrderBy() calls". At least, that's been my experience.

Answer (score 1):

1.As I understand grouped by key stock records should be ordered by key descending. At least you have so set up your unit test expectations. But in your action method query I am not seeing descending ordering by key. You need to add it:

```
IEnumerable<StockRecord>[] records = repository.StockRecords
    .Where(r => symbols.Contains(r.Symbol))
    .GroupBy(r => r.Symbol)
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.Key)              
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(g2 => g2.RecordDate).Take(30).OrderBy(p => p.RecordDate))                          
    .ToArray();
return Json(records, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

2.Such casting `IGrouping<string, StockRecord>[] allStocks = (IGrouping<string, StockRecord>[])result.Data` will not compile. You can replace it with `IEnumerable<StockRecord>[] allStocks = (IEnumerable<StockRecord>[]) result.Data;`

Then it will behave according to expcetations defined by you in unit test

Answer (score 1):

I was just being stupid. It was going to a different query that was sorting it that way. This is what I ended up with:

**ACTION METHOD**

```
    public ActionResult GetStockHistory(string[] symbols, int maxRows = Int32.MaxValue)
    {
        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<StockRecord>> records;

        records = repository.StockRecords
            .Where(r => symbols.Contains(r.Symbol))
            .GroupBy(r => r.Symbol)
            .Select(g => g
                .OrderByDescending(g2 => g2.RecordDate)
                .Take(maxRows)
                .OrderBy(g3 => g3.RecordDate));

        return Json(records, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
    }
```

**UNIT TEST**

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Can_Get_Stock()
    {
        // arrange
        Mock<IStockHistory> mock = new Mock<IStockHistory>();
        mock.Setup(m => m.StockRecords).Returns(new StockRecord[] {
            new StockRecord { 
                Symbol = "ABCDEFG", 
                RecordDate = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1)
            }
        }.AsQueryable());
        CommonController target = new CommonController(mock.Object);

        // act
        JsonResult result = (JsonResult)target.GetStockHistory(new string[] { "ABCDEFG" });
        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<StockRecord>> allStocks = (IEnumerable<IEnumerable<StockRecord>>)result.Data;

        // assert
        Assert.AreEqual(1, allStocks.Count());
        StockRecord[] record1 = allStocks.ElementAt(0).ToArray();
        StockRecord record1_row1 = record1[0];

        Assert.AreEqual("ABCDEFG", record1_row1.Symbol);
    }
```